# Which operators break the general pattern for DP cost progression?

Tags: arknights

In the hero-collector tower defense game *Arknights*, each Operator (unit) has a DP Cost, which can change as the unit is enhanced/developed by the player. Most Operators follow the same pattern:

- As new units, they start with some specific DP cost *(let's say 16, for example)*
- Promoting the unit to Elite One rank increases their DP cost by 2 *(to 18, in our example)*
- Increasing the unit to their maximum Potential grants two separate DP cost reductions of 1, for a total of -2 *(back down to 16)*

Units of at least four-star rarity can be promoted a second time to Elite Two rank, but this generally does not affect their DP Cost. Therefore, a fully maxed-out unit usually ends up with the same DP Cost as when that unit was brand new.

However, there are exceptions to the pattern. Some examples:

- Saria incurs an additional +2 to her DP Cost upon promotion to Elite Two rank, leading to a final DP Cost higher than her initial cost
- Grani benefits from three (rather than two) -1 DP Cost reductions when maximizing her Potential, leading to a final DP Cost lower than her initial cost
- Fang gains a Talent upon promotion to Elite One that reduces her DP Cost by 1, also leading to a final DP Cost lower than her initial cost

Which other Operators break from the pattern described above, and in what ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's is a list of operators that break the general pattern for DP cost progression

The operators are grouped by their type and sorted by rarity (indicated by [#] before their name) in a descending manner:

### Vanguards

1. [5*] **Zima**: her E1 Talent reduces her DP cost by one (1)
2. [5*] **Grani**: her Potential reduces her cost by three (3)
3. [3*] **Fang**: her E1 Talent reduces her DP cost by one (1)

### Defenders

Note: All Defenders gains two (2) more DP cost when promoting to E2

1. [5*] **Bison**: his Potential reduces his cost by three (3)

### Specialists

1. [5*] **Snowsant** (CN only): her Potential reduces her cost by three (3)
2. [4*] **Gravel**: her E1 Talent reduces her DP cost by one (1)

### Medics

1. [5*] **Ceylon**: her Potential reduces her cost by three (3)

### Snipers

The following operators gains two (2) more DP cost when promoted to E2:

1. [6*] **W** (CN only)
2. [5*] **Meteorite**
3. [5*] **Provence**
4. [5*] **Sesa** (CN only)
5. [4*] **Shirayuki**

Only one Sniper operator benefits from DP reduction from her E1 talent:

1. [3*] **Catapult**

### Guards

The following operators gains two (2) more DP cost when promoted to E2:

1. [6*] **Blaze**
2. [6*] **Ch'en**
3. [6*] **Hellagur**
4. [5*] **Bibeak** (CN only)
5. [5*] **Broca**  (CN only)
6. [5*] **Savage**: she also has no DP reduction from her Potential
7. [5*] **Specter**
8. [4*] **Cutter**  (CN only)
9. [4*] **Estelle**
10. [4*] **Utage**

The following operators benefit from having three (3) DP cost reduction from their Potential:

1. [5*] **Flamebringer**
2. [5*] **Sideroca** (CN only)

One operator does not have any DP cost reduction from their Potential:

1. [4*] **Conviction** (CN only)

---

All of these data is accurate as of 1st of June, 2020

Source: [Aceship's Operator Details](https://aceship.github.io/AN-EN-Tags/akhrchars.html)

Comment: So all welfare operators get a 3 DP reduction from Potential?

Comment: Yes, they do. And its uncertain if future welfare operators would follow this pattern.